# Odd behavior of np.argsort with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan, np.argsort

Here is `np.argsort` applied in four different ways.

```
print(np.argsort([1,np.nan,3,np.nan, 4]))
print(np.argsort(pd.DataFrame([[1,np.nan,3,np.nan, 4]])).values)
print(np.argsort(pd.Series([1,np.nan,3,np.nan, 4]).values))  # same as first
print(np.argsort(pd.Series([1,np.nan,3,np.nan, 4])).values)
```

Output:

```
[0 2 4 1 3]
[[0 2 4 1 3]]
[0 2 4 1 3]
[ 0 -1  1 -1  2]
```

This is very unexpected behavior. No mention of it in numpy (obviously it will not mention Pandas).

In the Pandas documentation you can find

```
Returns: Series[np.intp]
Positions of values within the sort order with -1 indicating nan values.
```

Why? What would be a place where we would want this kind of behavior?

Comment: Doesn't `Series.argsort` explain itself well enough?  The first 3 lines are doing the usual `numpy` argsort - since `values` produces an array.  The last works on the Series directly, and passes the task to the Series method.  `np` has a number of functions that remove the `nan` before acting; that doesn't include a `nansort`, but that doesn't it can be done.

Comment: `Series.sort` has more options than `np.sort`, including a control as to where to put `nan` (first v last).